# SSRS - Blank grouping/duplication issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm sure this is a quick fix, but it's really got me scratching my head as I'm new to working on this level/type of issue in SSRS...

First screen:
http://www.pasteshack.net/images/579309001341850589.png

Second screen:
http://www.pasteshack.net/images/431284001341850718.png

I have had to blank out my companies information for obvious reasons, hopefully there's enough left there to answer my question.

I'm looking for the flt_Num column to always list the flt_number, even if it's duplicated. see http://www.pasteshack.net/images/431284001341850718.png flt_number 0125.

Have I explained what I'm after clearly enough? It's very frustrating and I'm hoping it's a simple solution.

Many thanks,
James.

Comment: Is `HideDuplicates` somehow set on that cell?

Comment: That was it! Don't know how I missed it. What's etiquette here, should I delete my question or would you like to post this as an answer so I can give your points?

Comment: I posted an answer and included a link to the documentation. Feel free to accept it. Btw, if you happen to find your own answer to your question it's ok to keep your question and answer it yourself. You'll be able to accept it in a couple of days. It adds to the wealth of information here. (Just remember to play along and ask the question as a question, then answer it below)

Comment: Oh, and as for missing it, these things are *easy* to miss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure [`HideDuplicates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152916%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is not set to true for the cell.